# continuous input characters like strings using loop multiple times

Tags: c++

In the following code, is it possible that I take multiple input, do some calculation (like the last character) and print at the end .. and then again take input till 5 times?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char name;
    int i=0;
    while(i != 5){

        while(!(name != '<' || name != '>')){
            cin>>name;
            //do some calculation with the inputs
            //cout<<name;
        }
        i++;
        cout<<name;
        //print the result of calculation this loop
    }
}
```

For some reason, I am not allowed to use `string`, or `array`, or `break`, and no library other than `iostream`. Is it possible using loops? What are alternatives?

**EDIT::** In above code, I want to determine what was last input. If I enter `asdf>` then i get `>>>>>`. I want it to print `>` and go back in the loop and ask me for another shot.

Comment: It's unclear what you're stuck on.  The "some calculation" part?  Looping 5 times?

Comment: suppose in above I enter `asfas<` i get `<<<<<` and the program terminates. I do not want the program to terminate .. instead I want to back to while loop inside that asks me more to input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the inner `while` terminates `name` holds either `<` or `>` and is not reset prior to the next encounter of the inner `while`, which terminates immediately as `name` is still either `<` or `>`. Just reset `name` prior to the inner `while` or slight restructure:

```
while (cin >> name && !(name != '<' || name != '>'))
{
}
```

Comment: thanks I was being stupid .. :(( should have realized earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to reset the name variable right before this line:

```
while (!(name != '<' || name != '>')) {
```

What you need to do would be this:

```
name = 0;
```

Also, I'd recommend initializing the variable before entering the first while loop.

Edit:
Alternatively, you can use `'\0'` instead of  `0`. It makes no difference internally though. The code would only make more sense to most inexperienced users.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to make a pointer to a character.  This will behave just like an array without actually being an array, and requires nothing but `#include <iostream>` for the input and output.

```
char* name;
```

You could also try using a vector of characters, but this is the long way around and would break the "nothing but `<iostream>` rule:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<char> CharVec;
vector<char>::iterator it;

int main ()
{
    char input;
    int i=0;
    while(i != 5){
        if(input != '<'){ //this should be if, not while
            CharVec.push_back(input);
        }
        i++;
    }
    //move print to outside the character entering loop
    it = CharVec.begin();
    while(it != CharVec.end())
    {
        cout << *it;
        it++;
    }
```

}

Comment: - He said no arrays
- He said nothing other than <iostream>

Comment: I can't use array ... or any data structures. This is h/w before arrays are taught. Is it possible using loops?

Comment: Well technically I have just made a pointer that behaves like an array.  The vector stuff is granted breaking the rule, but would your teacher/professor consider `char* c` to be the same as `char c[5]`?